# How to implement an upper bound JSD loss in Pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I’m trying to “replicate” [TextGAN](https://zhegan27.github.io/Papers/textGAN_nips2016_workshop.pdf) using pytorch and I’m new to pytorch. My current concern is to replicate the L_G (eq. 7 page 3), and here’s my current code:

```py
class JSDLoss(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(JSDLoss,self).__init__()

    def forward(self, batch_size, f_real, f_synt):
        assert f_real.size()[1] == f_synt.size()[1]

        f_num_features = f_real.size()[1]
        identity = autograd.Variable(torch.eye(f_num_features)*0.1, requires_grad=False)

        if use_cuda:
            identity = identity.cuda(gpu)

        f_real_mean = torch.mean(f_real, 0, keepdim=True)
        f_synt_mean = torch.mean(f_synt, 0, keepdim=True)

        dev_f_real = f_real - f_real_mean.expand(batch_size,f_num_features)
        dev_f_synt = f_synt - f_synt_mean.expand(batch_size,f_num_features)

        f_real_xx = torch.mm(torch.t(dev_f_real), dev_f_real)
        f_synt_xx = torch.mm(torch.t(dev_f_synt), dev_f_synt)

        cov_mat_f_real = (f_real_xx / batch_size) - torch.mm(f_real_mean, torch.t(f_real_mean)) + identity
        cov_mat_f_synt = (f_synt_xx / batch_size) - torch.mm(f_synt_mean, torch.t(f_synt_mean)) + identity

        cov_mat_f_real_inv = torch.inverse(cov_mat_f_real)
        cov_mat_f_synt_inv = torch.inverse(cov_mat_f_synt)

        temp1 = torch.trace(torch.add(torch.mm(cov_mat_f_synt_inv, cov_mat_f_real), torch.mm(cov_mat_f_real_inv, cov_mat_f_synt)))
        temp1 = temp1.view(1,1)
        temp2 = torch.mm(torch.mm((f_synt_mean - f_real_mean), (cov_mat_f_synt_inv + cov_mat_f_real_inv)), torch.t(f_synt_mean - f_real_mean))
        loss_g = torch.add(temp1, temp2).mean()

        return loss_g
```

It works. However, I have a suspicion that it's not the way to create a custom loss. Any kind of help is well appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

**How to create a custom loss in Pytorch**

This is how you create a custom loss in Pytorch. You need to meet the following requirements:

> - The value finally being returned by a loss function MUST BE a scalar    value. Not a vector/tensor.
> - The value being returned must be a Variable. This is so that it can be used to update the parameters in your model. The best way to do so
>     is to just make sure that both x and y being passed in are Variables.
>     That way any function of the two will also be a Variable.
> - Define the `__init__` and `forward` methods

You can find several loss modules that you can use as examples in the Pytorch source code: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/loss.py

If you are passing a mini-batch tensor to your loss function, then there is no need to pass the mini-batch size to the `forward` function, since the size can be calculated in the `forward` function.

**How you use a custom loss**

Once you have implemented your loss function, you can use it as follows, for example:

```
loss = YourLoss()
input = autograd.Variable(torch.randn(3, 5), requires_grad=True)
target = autograd.Variable(torch.randn(3, 5))
output = loss(input, target)
output.backward()
```

`loss.backward()` computes `dloss/dx` for every parameter `x` in your network which has `requires_grad=True`. These are accumulated into `x.grad` for every parameter `x`. In pseudo-code:

```
x.grad += dloss/dx
```

optimizer.step updates the value of `x` using the gradient `x.grad`. For example, the SGD optimizer performs:

```
x += -lr * x.grad
```

`optimizer.zero_grad()` clears `x.grad` for every parameter `x` in the optimizer. It’s important to call this before `loss.backward()`, otherwise you’ll accumulate the gradients from multiple passes.

Comment: thanks a lot for the comment @JMA. I pretty much already knew how to make loss function and all, my question actually focused more on whether or not I use the correct equation or reflective of the paper's equation. It would mean the whole world if you can help me on this :)

Comment: Do you still need help verifying this?

Comment: yes, i'm also ok if you want to move the discussion to email